# What is the equivalent of Intellij KeyPromoter for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I cannot find the equivalent of Intellij KeyPromoter for Eclipse IDE. Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This? https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mousefeed

Comment: Hmmm... can be, but mostly I am looking for a plugin which will fill automatically, e.g. if I enter 'sout' then it will display System.out.println(); automaticaly

Comment: Okay, I've found the answer!) You need to enter syso and then hit Ctrl+Space, then it will autofill the line:)

Comment: I am wondering what about psvm, because it doesn't work in the way highlighted above. :|

Comment: `psvm` is in Eclipse `main` for reasons.

Comment: @howlger Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

#### Similar Plugins

Similar to IntelliJ's plugin [Key Promoter X](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9792-key-promoter-x) is Eclipse's plugin:

- [MouseFeed](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mousefeed) (like [howlger suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829953/what-is-the-equivalent-of-intellij-keypromoter-for-eclipse#comment96435418_54829953)).

#### Built-in since 4.13

Since Eclipse version 4.13 (released in September 2019) this functionality is built-in. See "Show Keybinding" in [Eclipse Project 4.13 - New and Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#show-keybinding):

> **Show key bindings when command is invoked**
>
> For presentations, screen casts and learning purposes, it is very helpful to show the corresponding key binding when a command is invoked. When the command is invoked (via a key binding or menu interaction) the key binding, the command's name and description are shown on the screen.

[image: preview of show key-binding]

> You can activate this in the **Preferences** dialog via the Show key binding when command is invoked check box on the **General > Keys** preference page. To toggle this setting quickly the command 'Toggle Whether to Show Key Binding' can be used (e.g. via the quick access).